# How to push image out from the view in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I am new to Flutter and I'd like to know how to achieve this design in my project.

1. How do I transform/translate my background in a way that it goes up and out from the view?
2. How do I add another container (positioned bottom of the screen) on top of my background after a few milliseconds?

[gif demonstrating the design I'd like to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ypjlm.gif)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **showModalBottomSheet**. Here's an example

```
 onPressed: () {
              showModalBottomSheet(
                  context: context,
                  builder: (BuildContext ctx) {
                    return Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                      child: Container() //add any widget here
                    );
              
                  });
            }
```

For first question, put your image in an AnimatedAlign widget

Answer (score 0):

you can use this, [sliding_up_panel](https://pub.dev/packages/sliding_up_panel) with parallax effect:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text("SlidingUpPanelExample"),
    ),
    body: SlidingUpPanel(
      parallaxEnabled: true,
      panel: Center(
        child: Text("This is the sliding Widget"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text("This is the Widget behind the sliding panel"),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```